# JQuery - Find classes with a wildcard

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have multiple classes throughout my page that are like:

```
<input class="someclass1 condition[operator]" type="text">
<input class="someclass2 condition[value]" type="text">
<input class="condition[percentage]" type="text">
```

I'd like to use jquery to basically loop through `find("some_selector_i_need").each()` but I'm not sure how to do this with wildcards.

Is this even possible? Something like `find("condition[*]").each()` where I could pull out what the `*` is as well?

I'd eventually like to format an array like:

```
Array
(
  operator => 'value1',
  value => 'value2',
  percentage => 'value3'
)
```

Comment: It's possible, I'm sure you'll get an answer quickly (using an attribute selector for starts with condition[ and then something), I just thought I'd let you know, chances are that's the wrong approach. What are you actually doing?

Comment: Arrays don't have keys like that in javascript, objects do ?

Comment: @adeneo: Looks like a PHP output.

Comment: @FelixKling - You're right, probably is PHP syntax.

Answer (score 9):

```
var obj = {};

$('[class*="condition"]').each(function(i,ele) {
    var type = ele.className.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];
    obj[type] = 'value' + (i+1);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/G89jx/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.find("[class*=condition]").each()
```